# WordPress not emailing me when there is a new comment

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I've just built a custom WordPress theme with the default comment system enabled for the first time.

I have 3 users (administrators) registered on the admin side. For each of those users, in the Settings > Discussion tab I have "Email me whenever anyone posts a comment", and "Email me whenever a comment is held for moderation" checked. I posted a test comment on a blog post, but WordPress is not sending any emails to anyone. I have double checked the email addresses and checked spam folders.

Am I missing a function in my functions.php file? Is there anything else that I'm not thinking of that could be inhibiting WordPress from sending out emails?

Thanks! (Sorry, I'm still new to this commenting system).

Comment: Its possible your host is not allowing PHP's `mail()` or WordPress' `wp_mail()`. I have seen this happen. If that is the case you will need to configure an SMTP connection for send any emails. This is a highly popular plugin for that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/, but for the first step, check with your host that the functions mentioned above are enabled.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll check in with them and see if that could be the problem. :)

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to hear, glad to help!